# What is the absolute value on $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ in this context?

Tags: absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the ring of p-adic integers for some prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What is the absolute value on $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ ?

The motivation for the question comes from a proof of Hensel's lemma where we construct a sequence of polynomials $g_n(X) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ such that $g_n(X) \to g(X)$. I would like to make sure that I understand what exactly $g_n(X) \to g(X)$ means in this context. The proof is found on page 74 in the book "p-adic Numbers" by Gouvea.

Can we just take $\lvert a_o + a_1X + \cdots + a_nX^n\rvert_p:= \underset{0 \leq i \leq n} \max \lvert a_i \rvert_p$ ? 
This would satisfy the triangle inequality and positive-definiteness. However I am not convinced that the multiplicative property holds.

EDIT: Or perhaps I am mistaken looking for an absolute value in this context. Perhaps I am really looking for a norm, in which case the suggestion should work.

Comment: It means the coefficients of $g_n(X)$ approach the coefficients of $g(X)$ pointwise. The norm you suggested works; there is no reason to look for an absolute value.

Comment: It is in fact multiplicative - it is the restriction of the Gauss norm on the [Tate algebra](http://kskedlaya.org/18.727/tate-algebras.pdf) (a Banach algebra) to the sub-algebra of polynomials. Then you could say $g_n(X)\to g(X)$ if it converges in the Banach algebra $T$, although as Qiaochu notes, you don't need anything so high-powered in your situation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, I kind of realized once I asked the question. I got confused since the book has focused so much on absolute values to measure distance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra))? The $p$-adic valuation gives a metric on $\mathbb Q$ and this is used a lot. I am unfamiliar with the particular proof, but the ones I have seen have only used valuations on evaluations on polynomials or similar.

In any case, there're possible generalisations of the $p$-adic valuation (socratean question: how would you define it?) to the ring in question, and the most natural one can be made to satisfy the properties you want if I remember correctly.

further edit: As I alluded to and as the topmost comment points out, there is no need to take this too far since the proof doesn't need it.